# Publish a menu item but dont show it

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system

I have a situation where we have a "user menu" on the top of the page.This menu is shown on every page with a module.Now in order to set up breadcrumbs properly I need to have a menu item which is published but not visible to any type of user whether guest or registered..

Is it possible in Joomla to have a menu item published and hidden yet accesible via URL??

Comment: what is the name of your module which displays the breadcrumbs

Comment: It is default module which ships with Joomla

Comment: Then i guess you will need to modify the code.

Comment: Yup..Knew that.but thought there may be a better way of doing this.bdw customizing menu module and not feeling right!!!

Comment: You could use CSS and hide it only for visitors, but it is still there

Comment: You are right..But I dont't think that we should do that..do we?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a different module which had most of the functionality of your custom module. In the new module you can change the code in a way so that you dont show the required menu.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create a menu, setup user groups, view level. Create a menu item, and try to access via menu alis - link.
Good luck

Comment: That is a general approach but doesn't come handy as per my situation..I really don't want to show the menu item ..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Menu's are independent of the modules that display them, it's possible to create a menu and not create a menu module, how, depends on the version of Joomla you are using.

That's why there are so hits when you [Google — "Joomla Hidden Menu"](https://www.google.com/search?q=joomla%20hidden%20menu) There is even an article on [Joomla Doc's](http://docs.joomla.org/) on "[Menus](http://docs.joomla.org/Menu)" that discusses hidden menus briefly.

So, the normal approach is to create a new Menu with a name like "Hidden" or "Shortcuts" and have the menu items created in that menu, then **don't** assign a menu module for it.